# add small timer to activity until wifi restarts?

Tags: android, android-wifi

i am developing an android app that toggles on wifi and when it turns on performs further processing..

```
wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
```

but the condition ..

```
wifiEnabled = wifiManager.isWifiEnabled();


if(wifiEnabled )
{ ...... }
```

always returns False since wifi takes time to reconnect 
how do i wait until it restarts or actually connects to a wifi network..

i know the condition that i can use to check if it's actually connected or connecting.

```
Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnectedOrConnecting();
Boolean isWifi = manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected();
```

*my two question?*

**1- wait until wifi is enabled i.e. toggled on?
2- wait untli it actually connects to a wifi network?**

Answer (score 2):

> 1- wait until wifi is enabled i.e. toggled on? 2- wait untli it
>   actually connects to a wifi network?

You can for both events create [BroadcastReceiver](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html) and then perform specific actions:

```
public class WifiStateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

   // action for Wi-Fi device status changes (enabled, disabled etc.)
   if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {

      // get actual status of Wi-Fi
      int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, 
                                     WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_UNKNOWN);

     if (state == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED) {
        // do your stuff
     }

     ...

     // similar for WIFI_STATE_DISABLED
   }

   // action for connectivity changes (connected, disconnected etc.)
   if (intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)) {

      NetworkInfo ni = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

      if (ni.getState().equals(NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)) {
         // do your stuff if is connected
      }

      ...

      // similar for DISCONNECTED
   }
}
```

If you want to know more connectivity states (connecting, obtaining ip address etc.), you need to use:

```
networkInfo.getDetailedState();
```

this also depends on actual API level on device.

And finally you need these Intent-filters for BroadcastReceiver:

```
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
```

**Refs:**

- [Android BroadcastReceiver Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you really need WIFI connection to proceed with your app logic you will have to wait. Said that, you could create an AsyncTask to handle the "waiting" situation. 
That `AsyncTask` would present a `ProgressDialog` indicating the wifi connecting status.

If the user must toggle wifi ON manually the AsyncTask will run after **wifiEnabled = true** and will be stopped when `manager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).isConnected()` == true.

I don't know if this answer helps you but this is my interpretation of your question.
Take care, hope it helps.